# Как использовать правильно bitset

Tags: c++

Не могу понять, что делает данный код:

```
bitset<365> x[365];
int intersection(int i, int j) {
  return (x[i] & x[j]).count();
}
```

У меня есть битсет на 365 битов и я ожидаю, что могу включать или выключать в нем какие-то биты и я ХОТЕЛ бы иметь возможность сравнивать его с другими битовыми масками.. будь то число или другой битсет.

А что происходит в `intersection`? Каким образом мне каких-то два числа переданных в аргументы могут дать информацию о пересечении битов? Что они вообще дают и почему я достаю эти числа по индексу с битсета?

Ноль идей что происходит.

Comment: @AlexF я как-то не пойму сам синтаксис. Ну есть у нас дни, но почему мы `int` передаем как `x[i]`, `x[j]`. Как я вообще в битсет по индексу передаю `int`?? Не понятно.

Comment: @AlexF тот факт, что это дни в году я как бы понимаю.. но . . как? что происходит вообще? как образом эти два дня к этому битсету и по индеку?

Comment: @AlexF то что он ДОЛЖЕН делать я понимаю. вопрос.. повторюсь третий раз.. в том КАК он это делает.  `00000000000000...365` вот это битсет. int day = `0000...32` это инт. bitset[i] - это какой-то битиз битсета. Каким образом bitset[day] дает мне какое-то значение по пересичение?

Answer (score 0):

1. Объявлен массив из 365 битовых множеств в 365 битов.
2. Функция возвращает количеством единиц в битовом множестве, полученное  в результате  операции логического "и" `i_того`
   множества с  `j_том` множестве. ( Поскольку ничего
   не инициализировано, то все биты будут нулями, и результат будет
   нулем.

P.S. может быть вы хотели

```
int intersection(const int i, const int j) {
    std::bitset<365> b1(i),
        b2(j);
    return (b1 & b2).count();
}
```

или

```
int intersection(const std::bitset<365>& i, const std::bitset<365>& j) {

    return (i & j).count();
}
```

или и их перегрузку?...

Comment: первый пример имеет для меня смысл.. но там `b1(1), b2(j)`, мы как бы передает эти даты в битсеты отдельные и их сравнием. это могу понять. 
но почему так именно дни передаются в рандом-аксес оператор? Каким образом по индексу мы можем понять сколько в тех двух днях пересечений?